# Update Items using Odata4j 0.3

Tags: java, odata, odata4j

At first we tried to use Odata4j 0.7 but it was giving me null exception and by the way it is a reported bug but I didn't find a fix/patch for it so tried to use different version until I could connect to my WCF Data Service with Odata4j 0.3 version

Now I couldn't update items using it ? It gave me a wrong query syntax exception

Comment: Exception stack trace needed, please. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Which OData version is the service that you tried to consume? If you are connecting to a OData service prior to OData version 3.0, you can use the OData Java client of the [Apache Olingo project](http://olingo.apache.org/). And I would also recommend you follow this project as they will upgrade their OData Java client to support OData version 4.0, if you have requirements to talk to OData v4 services.

Besides, it seems that the OData4J project is not maintained anymore.